# Chrome print style changes on second preview

Tags: css, google-chrome

When I load our web page and select print on Chrome the print preview displays fine. However, if I cancel the preview then select print again the preview now shows many elements scaled down and the preview is quite different to the first one. Third and fourth previews are the same as the second (incorrect) one.

What options are there to fix this?

print.css: http://pastebin.com/6bnkB9ai